# Unable to activate instance of type Com.ViewPagerIndicator.CirclePageIndicator from native handle

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im just getting this error on android side. Im using CarouselView.FormsPlugin for slider on my 2 page. First one is registration form which as navigation page. After that using tabbed main page which has another slider for show images.

When i click next button to complete register form it gives me that error.

```
    private void NavButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new TabbedPage1();
    }
```

Full Error: Unhandled Exception:

System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Com.ViewPagerIndicator.CirclePageIndicator from native handle 0xbfe3d69c (key_handle 0x9d8c998). occurred

Im not getting any error on IOS and when i remove slider on register page.

This is how i show first (register forms slider):

```
                <controls:CarouselViewControl ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionList}"
                                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                      ShowIndicators="True"
                                      ShowArrows="False"
                                      Position="0"                                          
                                      IndicatorsTintColor="White"
                                      CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="#ffc625"
                                      AnimateTransition="True">
                    <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <aboutmydogquestionviews:AnswerboxQuestionView QuestionText="{Binding Q1.QuestionText}" HeightRequest="233"
                             QuestionSubText="{Binding Q1.QuestionSubText}" ShowAnswer="{Binding Q1.ShowAnswer}" ></aboutmydogquestionviews:AnswerboxQuestionView>
                                <aboutmydogquestionviews:AnswerboxQuestionView QuestionText="{Binding Q2.QuestionText}" HeightRequest="233" IsVisible="{Binding Q2,Converter={StaticResource IsNull}}"
                             QuestionSubText="{Binding Q2.QuestionSubText}" ShowAnswer="{Binding Q2.ShowAnswer}" ></aboutmydogquestionviews:AnswerboxQuestionView>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                </controls:CarouselViewControl>
```

Comment: are you trying to show carousel indicators

Comment: @G.hakim yes,its showing but after trying to set new page its getting broke.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of carousel forms?

Comment: @G.hakim ofcourse mate.

Comment: According to my understanding, you have one CarouselViewControl control in Mainpage, there are two items in CarouselViewControl, when you navigate the second page, you want to click button to replace the project current MainPage by TabbedPage1, am I right?

Comment: @CherryBu exactly right.

Comment: I'm getting a similar error. When displaying a modal page with a carousel and popping the page from the navigation stack and displaying the main page that also contains a carouse. Any solution to this?

Comment: It's a bug with the project `CarouselView.FormsPlugin`. In order to fix it, you need to add a project called `CirclePageIndicator` from the same author. (Or you can wait the author fix the Carousel project).

Comment: @NickeManarin Thanks, that actually worked. You should post this as an answer

Comment: @NickeManarin i just solved it with using CardView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with the project `CarouselView.FormsPlugin`.

In order to fix it, you need to add a project called [`CirclePageIndicator` (v1.0.3)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.CirclePageIndicator/) from the same author to the Android project (or you can wait for the author to fix the Carousel plugin).

Answer (score 0):

> you have one CarouselViewControl control in Mainpage, there are two items in CarouselViewControl, when you navigate the second page, you want to click button to replace the project current MainPage by TabbedPage1

If you want to do this, I do one sample that you can take a look, and I don't get any error message.

Page7.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
  x:Class="test2.Page7"
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:abstractions="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions">
<abstractions:CarouselViewControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding pages}"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    PositionSelectedCommand="{Binding Mycommand}"
    ShowArrows="true"
    ShowIndicators="true">
    <abstractions:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView Content="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </abstractions:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
</abstractions:CarouselViewControl>

</ContentPage>

public partial class Page7 : ContentPage
{
    public Page7()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = "CarouselView";
        this.BindingContext = new MainViewModel1();
    }    
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel1
{
    public List<ContentView> pages { get; set; }
    public Command Mycommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel1()
    {
        pages = new List<ContentView>();
        pages.Add(new View1());
        pages.Add(new View2());

        Mycommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Position selected!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        });          
    }
}
```

View1.cs, this is contentview

```
public class View1 : ContentView
{
    public View1 ()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

View2.cs,this is contentview

```
public class View2 : ContentView
{
    public View2 ()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" },
                new Button{Text="btn1", WidthRequest=80,HeightRequest=50,Command=new Command(()=>{App.Current.MainPage=new TabbedPage1(); })}

            }
        };
    }
}
```

[image]